# How to manually convert between fixed type and floating type?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, fixed-point

I am using a library which has **fixed point** variables.The library is called **libfixmath**.

I am trying to see how a number gets converted from a fix16_t to a float type. I understand it uses 32 bits (16 MSB bits for integers and 16 LSB bits for decimals) to represent a number.

This is the code I tried, here "sum" is of type fix16_t.

```
float in_sum = fix16_to_float(sum);
printf("fix16 type sum:%u\n",sum);
printf("float type sum:%f\n",in_sum);
```

I display the "sum" in an unsigned integer format, again I'm not sure the best format to display the "sum" value.

A sample output I got is:

```
fix16 type sum:4064807395
float type sum:-3511.961426
```

I had a look at the conversion function:

```
static inline float   fix16_to_float(fix16_t a) { return (float)a / fix16_one; }
```

Where `fix16_one` is 65536.

To get a better understanding I want to be able to convert this manually, but I do not know how. I am confused with the type casting `(float)a`.

Another question I have is, are the 16 integer bits signed or unsigned?

Comment: What is the *actual* type of `fix16_t`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the library it is defined like this "typedef int32_t fix16_t"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fix16_t` is an integer type, then `a / 65536` would be an *integer* division, without any decimals. For example `65535 / 65536` is not the floating point value `0.99998`, but the integer value `0`.

The casting of `a` converts `a` and therefore the whole expression into a floating point division, with decimals.

---

Using the values:

1. Integer division: `-230159901 / 65536` will result in the *integer* value `-3511`.
2. Floating point division: `(float)-230159901 / 65536` will result in the `float` value `-3511.961426`.

Comment: When I use a calculator to do 4064807395 / 65536. I get 62024. Which is not what the program calculates (which is -3511).
What calculation can I use to get the same as the example?

Comment: @ghostwar88 The problem is one of *undefined behavior* in your `printf` call. The `"%u"` format is for ***unsigned*** `int`, while the type `int32_t` is ***signed*** (and should therefore use `"%d"`, or better yet `printf("fix16 type sum:"PRId32"\n", sum);`) The actual value isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Comment: using '%d' I got ' fix16 type sum:-230159901 float type sum:-3511.961426 ', but using 'PRId32', I just got 'fix16 type sum:d'

Comment: @ghostwar88 Ah I forgot the `%`: `printf("fix16 type sum:%"PRId32"\n", sum);` It should give the same result though (`-230159901`).

Comment: Ok, I get the same result as using `%d`. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Re “with decimals”: Dividing binary floating-point numbers may create fractional (non-integral) values, not decimals. Consider binary floating-point data as decimal leads to incorrect and/or inaccurate reasoning about behavior.